# Excel VBA Storing time specific value into cell from userform

Tags: vba, datetime, excel, date-formatting

I have a userform that requires the user to input a specific date and time through two separate comboboxes, cboStartDate, cboStartTime. The user will also have to input the duration  in a text field, txtDuration.

Upon saving, the start date and time will be stored in a formatted cell [DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM]. The end date and time will be calculated from the duration field and stored in another cell with the same formatting. Something like this:

```
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| startTime             | endTime               |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| 2/4/2012  11:30:00 AM | 2/4/2012  2:00:00 PM  |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

However, after running the userform through, the start time is not stored, and the end time is not calculated. Something like this:

```
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| startTime             | endTime               |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| 2/4/2012  12:00:00 AM | 2/4/2012  12:00:00 AM |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

Below is my part of my VBA code:

```
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim startDate As Date
Dim unFmtStartDuration() As String
Dim startDuration As Double
Dim minTest As Integer
Dim endDate As Date
Dim endDuration As Double

Set ws = Worksheets("EVENTS")

'Search for the last row in the worksheet
iRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

'Date manipulation and set start and end timings
unFmtStartDuration() = Split(cboStartTime.Text, ":")
startDuration = unFmtStartDuration(0)
If unFmtStartDuration(1) = "00" Then
    minTest = 0
Else
    minTest = unFmtStartDuration(1)
    If minTest = 30 Then
        startDuration = startDuration + 0.5
    End If
End If
startDate = DateValue(DateAdd("h", startDuration, cboDate.Text & " 12:00AM"))
ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = startDate
endDuration = txtDuration.Value
endDate = DateValue(DateAdd("h", endDuration, startDate))
ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = endDate
```

So how can I get this part sorted out? Would appreciate any help here. Thanks.

P.S. Would like to post screenshots here, but my reputation here is too low for it. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are only adding the time when `minTest = 30`, but this value probably varies quite a bit. Also, in one instance, you are comparing a string, and another a number when referencing `unFmtStartDuration`, which may work, but is confusing when reading your code.

To follow your current method, use

```
startDuration = Val(unFmtStartDuration(0) + Round(Val(unFmtStartDuration(1)) / 60, 2)
```

to replace this

```
startDuration = unFmtStartDuration(0)
If unFmtStartDuration(1) = "00" Then
    minTest = 0
Else
    minTest = unFmtStartDuration(1)
    If minTest = 30 Then
        startDuration = startDuration + 0.5
    End If
End If
```

This will take whatever the time is and convert it to the decimal form you are using, instead of relying on the `30` match. (Unless you need that specifically. If so, say so, as I think this can still be arranged with rounding tricks.)

However, I think a better option would be to use

```
startDuration = TimeValue(cboStartTime.Text) * 24
```

So no other math or checks are involved.

Also, unless `cboStartTime.Text` (and subsequently `startDuration`) is greater than 24 hours, this

```
startDate = DateValue(DateAdd("h", startDuration, cboDate.Text & " 12:00AM"))
```

will always return the date specified in `cboDate.Text` with an implied **12:00:00 AM**. To correct this, you will want to change to

```
startDate = DateAdd("h", startDuration, cboDate.Text & " 12:00AM")
```

I think there is some more to fix, but hopefully this gets you going in the right direction...

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I did not consider `TimeValue()` function initially because I am quite new to using VBA. Used it in the codes and its beautiful. Nonetheless, thanks for your help! It works well now... By the way, somehow the `DateAdd` function could not add 0.5 in h for some reasons... resorted to splitting the startTime and endTime into hours and minutes instead as a quick fix. P.S. wished that I can upvote, once again rep is too low... :(

Comment: Thanks, @SiddharthRout. And don't worry Robert; stick around and you'll get up there in rep. :-)